# Django - Inception style transaction handling

Tags: python, database, django, transactions

I'm no transaction / database expert, so pardon my ignorance in the wording here:

When you use Django's `transaction.commit_on_success(func)`, any error that's propagated to the control of `commit_on_success` will roll back the transaction which is really helpful of course in case you need some all-or-nothing action in a method, etc. This makes Django's view-based transaction handling great for views that do a lot of stuff.

Sometimes I wrap model methods or plain old helper functions in `commit_on_success` to achieve the same all-or-nothing behavior.

The **problem** comes when you have nested Django transactions. Example: A transaction protected view calls a model method that's wrapped in `commit_on_success` and then does some other stuff with another model and causes an exception. Oops, when control returned to `commit_on_success` from the model method the transaction was committed and now the view errors out changing my view to all-or-some instead of all-or-nothing. This isn't limited to views. I may have nested operations going on which all `lots_o_foo_or_nothing()` uses `commit_on_success` and calls `all_or_nothing_1()` and `all_or_nothing_2()` which are both wrapped in `commit_on_success`. If `lots_o_foo_or_nothing()` errors out the sub function calls will have already committed their transactions to the DB, logically corrupting my data.

Is there a way around this? Again, pardon me, if I'm misunderstanding something, but it seems this is the behavior I've witnessed, and a way around it would be a great convenience.

Comment: savepoints? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/transactions/#savepoints

Comment: @Jerzyk - how will that fix the problem? If I save manually, I can roll back manually from within my context. What if I save in a local scope and then an error happens above that scope, propagating to the request scope? The request transaction handling cannot at this point roll back anything you've committed manually.

Comment: few ideas: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1343/ (my idea was to use something like this plus savepoints) looking further it looks like this/similiar issues are known for at least few years: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2227

Comment: @Jerzyk - thx, put that into an answer so I can up-vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not a final solution but an idea based on this [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1343) (which is good idea per se)

this plus [savepoints](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/transactions/#savepoints) can create nice solution: a decorator, which will be aware if transaction is inside other transaction (and if it is, is using savepoints instead of transactions).

Comment: I like this, drop a save point going into the inner commit_on_save and if you exception out of it roll back to the save point. That would produce exactly the behavior I naively expected.